# ExecuteException: : Process exited with an error: -1073740791 after mvn javafx:run command

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I created a simple JavaFX application to guess a number:

Main.java

```
package pl.diakowski.guessingnumber;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Odgadnij liczbę");

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    private static void setDarkMode(Stage stage, boolean darkMode) {

    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
package pl.diakowski.guessingnumber.controller;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.util.random.RandomGenerator;
import java.util.random.RandomGeneratorFactory;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TextField guessTextField;
    @FXML
    private Button guessButton;
    @FXML
    private Label messageLabel;
    private int targetNumber;
    private int attempts = 0;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        // Inicjalizacja gry przy ładowaniu interfejsu
        RandomGeneratorFactory<RandomGenerator> randomGeneratorFactory = RandomGeneratorFactory.getDefault();
        RandomGenerator randomGenerator = randomGeneratorFactory.create();
        targetNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(1, 100);
        System.out.println("Wylosowano liczbę: " + targetNumber);
        guessButton.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> onGuessButtonClick());
        guessTextField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode().toString().equals("ENTER")) {
                onGuessButtonClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void onGuessButtonClick() {
        try {
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessTextField.getText());
            attempts++;

            if (guess == targetNumber) {
                showResult("Gratulacje! Odgadłeś liczbę w " + attempts + " próbach.");
            } else if (guess < targetNumber) {
                messageLabel.setText("Za mało. Spróbuj jeszcze raz.");
            } else {
                messageLabel.setText("Za dużo. Spróbuj jeszcze raz.");
            }

            guessTextField.clear();
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            messageLabel.setText("Wprowadź poprawną liczbę.");
        }
    }

    private void showResult(String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Wynik");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(message);
        alert.showAndWait();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
module pl.diakowski.guessingnumber {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;


    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires com.sun.jna;

    opens pl.diakowski.guessingnumber to javafx.fxml;
    opens pl.diakowski.guessingnumber.controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports pl.diakowski.guessingnumber;
    exports pl.diakowski.guessingnumber.controller;

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>guessing-number</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>guessing-number</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>guessing-number/pl.diakowski.guessingnumber.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        &lt;!&ndash; Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run &ndash;&gt;
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>guessing-number/pl.diakowski.guessingnumber.Main</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I do the following commands:

```
mvn compile
mvn javafx:run
```

After running the second command I get the following error in console:

```
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073740791 (Exit value: -1073740791)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073740791 (Exit value: -1073740791)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I completely don't know what is wrong with the project. No info in stacktrace is being shown. Where should I look for a solution?
What's even more interesting, when I downloaded HelloFX and opened via IntelliJ IDEA, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean javafx:run`?

Comment: Start here -. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.

Comment: Running a [google search on the error id 1073740791](https://www.google.com?q=1073740791) shows that this can be caused by a low-level windows file system error. (I do not know that is actually the cause of your issue though).

Comment: Looking at the point in the plugin where it dies, it is [trying to execute a command line](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/openjfx/JavaFXBaseMojo.java#L567).  Further it looks like it logs the command line when it fails and you haven't included that in your output :-(.  You can copy the command line from the output and paste it into a console and you might get more info.  If you can't find it in the output, perhaps you can right-click the `javafx:run` in the maven panel and debug it with a breakpoint on the failing line in the plugin.

Comment: You don't need to use the `mvn javafx:run` command to run your app.  From Idea you can run the app as per [idea recommended instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).  Or you can use the `java` command from the command line with appropriate command line switches.

Comment: Perhaps the files in your Java or JavaFX distribution are corrupt.  Maybe check your disk for errors (fixing any if there are any), delete the existing Java and JavaFX distributions and download new versions of each (perhaps deleting your maven cache too).

Answer (score 0):

OK it looks like the problem is related to Nvidia driver: look at the Intelij documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#troubleshoot

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

> The problem is caused by an error in the NVIDIA driver. Update your driver to the latest version. For more information, refer to the community forum

Comment: My NVIDIA driver is up-to-date. Running program via IntelliJ IDEA works correctly.